# What should I notice when I design the database schema for data-mining use?

Tags: database, database-design, machine-learning, data-mining

I'm going to design a database. The data in the database will be used in data-mining purpose later. I want to know if there is a better practice or way to design the database so that it will be useful for data-mining use. Particularly what should I notice when I design the database schema for data-mining use?

Comment: I would say that we can't answer you question. People design database schemas when they know what to query and use data mining algorithms when they don't. In other word, if we could answer your question, you wouldn't need dm algorithms. Now, this is a very general comment, it can be false in practice. Can you provide more informations about what you mean by "used for datamining purpose" ?

Comment: you will want a denormalized database, aka a data warehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start to design a database with some introductory tutorials, like [introduction to data mining](http://dataminingtools.net/wiki/introduction_to_data_mining.php) or [spatial data and text mining](http://ptucse.loremate.com/dw/node/6). You will see that most of the approaches is focused around SQL relational databases. In creating a model see [building a model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/datamine.111/b28131/models_building.htm).

Comment: It seems that how we model that is far more important than what the schema looks like. But is there are bad schema design for data-mining purpose?

Comment: Bad practices are lack of database normalization and poor choice of modeling parameters.